# accessing cgi-bin throws 403

Tags: apache-2.2

```
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/         
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">                 
AllowOverride All              
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch                 
Order allow,deny                 
Allow from all         
</Directory>
```

i get 403.

my permission settings of  the /var/www/cgi-bin is

```
drwxrwxrwx 8 www-data www-data
```

Answer (score 2):

You realize that in apache configuration fragement your cgi-bin directory is **/usr/lib/cgi-bin**, but directory you mention checking the filesystem permissions on is **/var/www/cgi-bin**?  Which directory did you really want?  Do you need to update your configuration to point at /var/www/cgi-bin?

I also think that it isn't really that wise to have to have your cgi-bin directory owned/writable by the apache service account.  With this setup a buggy cgi script could be used to upload content to be executed by your server.